# What is #top and how can I use it on my site

Tags: html, hyperlink

I always see websites that has a link that says #top or #bottom that takes you to the top or bottom of the page. Can someone please tell me how I can use it on my website. I already tried saying `<a href="#top">` or `<a href="#bottom">` but it did not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This depends on what exactly you would like to be treated as top and bottom. To link to the very start of the page, you can use the URL `#`, as in `<a href="#">Start of page</a>`. To link to some specific element near the start, assign an `id` attribute to it, e.g. `<h1 id="top">Main heading</h1>`, and use that attribute value in a link, e.g. `<a href="#top">Start of page</a>`.

The bottom is a bit more tricky, since there is no predefined URL for it, and although you can use the `id` technique, the URL will refer to the *start* of the element. You could deal with this using an empty element at the very end of document body:

```
Last piece of real content.
<div id="bottom"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you would use e.g. `<a href="#bottom">End of page</a>`.

However, normally [links to start of page are worse than useless](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/totop.html), and links to end of page are no better. Every browser provides a simple way of getting to the start or to the end of any page.

Comment: “Back to Top links considered harmful” article from 2006, considered harmful. Won't someone please think of the tablet browsers.

Comment: @Adria is right
That article is _really_ old and no longer applies.
You can get screen readers to ignore elements of a page when reading it back so the "Back to Top" link wont cause issues for users with disabilities.
Tablets **do not** have native functionality for jumping back to the start of a page.
The argument that in page links confuse users is old hat, with more and more pages using AJAX users are becoming more and more used to links not always causing a page refresh, as long as clicking the link caused something to happen most users are fine with it.

Comment: iOS browsers usually jump back to the top when you tap the status bar.

Comment: This answer is incomplete.  Yes you can link to any `<a name="...">` or any `<a id="...">`, but `#top` DOES NOT require any such "anchor".  "#top" is built in to browsers, and you can link to it despite having no matching element on the page.

Comment: @machineghost You appear to be right in that `#top` works in Chrome and Firefox without requiring an element with that ID (also `#` alone does the same, whereas `#something-else` does nothing).  However, I can't find any specification on this (and `#bottom` does not work out of the box).

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#scroll-to-the-fragment-identifier has the full specified rules for handling those URL fragments, but the relevant line is: "If decodedFragment is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the string top, then the indicated part of the document is the top of the document; return."

Answer (score 5):

Hashing with an `id` will take you to the equivalent element with the `id` on the page.

So if you have a div like so:

```
<div id="top"></div>
```

and an anchor as such:

```
<a href="#top">Go to top div</a>
```

Clicking the anchor will take you to that divs place in the DOM.

Comment: Also can be used like `<a name="top"></a>`

Comment: @u_mulder That method is old and outdated, use id's instead.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple if a user is at the bottom of the page show them

```
<a href="#top">Go to the top</a>
```

Or if they are at the top of the page show them

```
<a href="#bottom">Go to bottom</a>
```